Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared
Hello everyone i am getting issues with apple login with firebase this issue is coming in case android
Here is the code which i have written
 Future<void> signInWithApple(SignInMethod flow, {LoginMethod? loginMethod}) async {
    this.loginMethod = loginMethod ?? authProvider.state.loginMethod;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('loginMethod: ${this.loginMethod}');
    }
    showLoader();
    try {
      // Configure webAuthenticationOptions for Android
      final authOptions = WebAuthenticationOptions(
        clientId: 'com.dev.applesignin', // Replace with your client ID
        redirectUri: Uri.parse('https://app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler'),
        // Replace with your redirect URI
      );
      // Start the sign-in flow
      final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email, AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName],
        webAuthenticationOptions: authOptions,
      );
      final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
        idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
        accessToken: appleCredential.authorizationCode,
      );
      await signInToFirebase(
        oauthCredential,
      );
      hideLoader();
    } catch (e) {
      hideLoader();
      // Handle error
      print("Error occurred during Apple authentication: $e");
    }
  }

Console logs
D/SystemUtils(23579): [isSystemApp] begin android.app.Application@74134b4
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isMultiWindow:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): hasVivoFreeformTasks:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isLittleVExist:0,userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): [isSystemApp] begin android.app.Application@74134b4
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isMultiWindow:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): hasVivoFreeformTasks:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isLittleVExist:0,userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): userId:0
[GoRouter] getting location for name: "createWallet"
[GoRouter] pushing /createWallet
I/flutter (23579): unhandled element <filter/>; Picture key: Svg loader
D/SystemUtils(23579): [isSystemApp] begin android.app.Application@74134b4
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isMultiWindow:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): hasVivoFreeformTasks:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isLittleVExist:0,userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): [isSystemApp] begin android.app.Application@74134b4
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isMultiWindow:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): hasVivoFreeformTasks:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isLittleVExist:0,userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): [isSystemApp] begin android.app.Application@74134b4
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isMultiWindow:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): hasVivoFreeformTasks:0,userId:0
D/ScreenUtils(23579): isLittleVExist:0,userId:0
D/SystemUtils(23579): userId:0
I/flutter (23579): loginMethod: LoginMethod.signUp
D/SessionLifecycleClient(23579): Sending lifecycle 2 to service
D/SessionLifecycleService(23579): Activity backgrounding at 141606119
I/FA      (23579): Application backgrounded at: timestamp_millis: 1719838599560
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend(23579): Making request to: https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
D/TrafficStats(23579): tagSocket(233) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend(23579): Status Code: 200
i have tried by clearing default browser and allowed the third party as well

Same issue here
